# Once I've generated a random Int between a range, how could I assign that integer to each letter in the alphabet?

Tags: java, arrays, random, type-conversion

New to arrays here... I want to get a random integer and set that integer to each individual letter in the alphabet like integer 1 = a. So that I can print a random letter in the alphabet without using a pre-existing java method for random string. I don't want to generate a random string this is the way I need it.

```
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Random Gen = new Random();

    String[] letters = new String[50];

    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    int randomInt = Gene.nextInt(26);

    String second = "" + randomInt;
    System.out.println(second);

    //Not sure what next....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(alphabet.charAt(randomInt))` will print the character at (zero-based) position `randomInt` in your `alphabet` string.

(Note that `randomInt == 0` will output `a`, `1` outputs `b` and so on.)

Adapt this to your need.

Comment: Oh nice this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative way of selecting a random character, this is in my opinion a more elegant solution if all you will ever need is lowercase characters. It more explicitly conveys that the generated character will be a random lowercase latin letter, because it does not use an `alphabet` string constant.

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final Random random = new Random();
    final String[] array = new String[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = String.valueOf(generateRandomLetter(random));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

private static char generateRandomLetter(Random random) {
    return (char) ('a' + random.nextInt(26));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alphabet.charAt(randomInt) would provide you the required random character from alphabet string.